# PHP - How to order data by ascending or descending

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a form that allows a user to retrieve information from a database.

Currently users are able to retrieve the information from the database with the code I have provided (probably terrible coding but it works).

Now I would like the data to display in an asc or dsc order depending on what the user selects on the form. But im not too sure how to go about doing that, any help in the right direction would be much appreciated!

The PHP that retrieves the information:

```
$sql = "SELECT RunnerID, EventID, Date, FinishTime, Position, CategoryID, AgeGrade, PB FROM Results";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 echo "<table><tr><th>RunnerID</th><th>EventID</th><th>Date</th><th>FinishTime</th><th>Position</th><th>CategoryID</th><th>AgeGrade</th><th>PB</th></tr>";

 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["RunnerID"]. "</td><td>" . $row["EventID"]. " </td><td>" . $row["Date"]. " </td><td>" . $row["FinishTime"]. " </td><td>" . $row["Position"]. " </td><td>" . $row["CategoryID"]. " </td><td>" . $row["AgeGrade"]. " </td><td>" . $row["PB"]. " </td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
} 
else {
 echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: You can add an ORDER BY statement in your SQL code

Comment: mysql manful [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Prove us you are human: http://stackoverflow.com/captcha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than having PHP do the work, it would be more standard to modify your SQL query to include `ORDER BY xxxx ASC` or `ORDER BY xxxx DESC`. If you have a form which you want to allow them to sort by, a decent alternative might be something like:

```
$userSelectedProperty = $_GET['ThePropertyIWantToSortOn'];
$userSelectedDirection = $_GET['TheDirectionIWantToSortBy'];
$sql = "SELECT RunnerID, EventID ... FROM Results ORDER BY "; // Note the extra space
switch ($userSelectedProperty)
{
    case 'name': { $sql .= "RunnerName"; break; }
    case 'age': { $sql .= "AgeGrade"; break; }
    ...
    default: { $sql .= "RunnerID"; break; } // By default, let's sort by ID
}
if ($userSelectedDirection == 'desc')
{
   $sql .= " DESC"; // Note the preceding space.
}
else
{
   $sql .= " ASC"; // Note the preceding space.
}
```

This way, the sorting is already done on the database, so you're retrieving the data back in the order you want it already. The reason that I'm using switch statements and if statements even when it looks like it's the same data is that it avoids a vulnerability known as **SQL injection**. Basically, if you just directly use the variable to build the SQL query, there's nothing stopping some malicious user from providing code that lets them modify the query's intention. For instance, if they passed in something like `MyName; DELETE FROM Results;` as the value for the form input used to generate the field `$userSelectedProperty`, the resulting `$sql` string would be something like `SELECT RunnerID ... FROM Results ORDER BY MyName; DELETE FROM Results;`. Well, that's *really bad* because to SQL, it's two valid statements. This isn't the best or most comprehensive definition if this is your first time hearing about it, but if you're curious about how to avoid it, I would suggest looking into SQL injection guides.

Comment: Im new to this and im clearly doing something stupid here but whenever i try to implement this I get i get no results back and just a blank page. Any ideas why?

Comment: I'd take a look at what your SQL query is before you ask the database. At some point (before or after the database query doesn't really matter), add `echo $sql;` and see what your query is saying. If you have phpMyAdmin available or command line MySQL, try executing the query yourself; these tools might say "Hey, your query has this problem here" and PHP just wasn't reporting it back to you. Usually when this happens, it's because your SQL query wasn't perfectly valid (unless you don't have any records in your table!)

Comment: However, if you're getting an *entirely* blank page, then maybe PHP *is* actually receiving an error, but your configuration is set up that if PHP gets an error, it silently aborts (this is usually the case when running on a production/public server -- you don't want your users to see sensitive code!). The solution would still be the same (though I might try adding `exit($sql)` instead of `echo` if you add `echo $sql` and still don't see any output).

Comment: As i suspected it was just me being stupid. The problem im having now is that when i submit my form no matter what options I select its always sorted by RunnerID asc

Comment: If you're using an HTML `<form>`, instead of `$_GET` you would use `$_POST`. So if your textbox is something like `<input type="text" id="SortField" />`, you could get that variable by code such as `$sortField = $_POST["SortField"];`

Comment: Thanks so much for everything! Now asc and dsc are working for 'RunnerID' but changing the form to select 'EventID' instead of 'RunnerID' does nothing, am i again just overlooking something simple?

Comment: For every field that you want to sort on, you will need to add a line to the `switch` statement from above. If you aren't familiar with them, switch statements are just like compressed if statements. What you're doing here is you're using as input the `$userSelectedProperty` and you're defining what action to take. So you will need to add a line `case "EventID": { $sql .= "EventID"; break; }` to make it work (and modify accordingly for each field. Note that you aren't sending `$userSelectedProperty` to MySQL - you're using it in PHP to determine what *to* send to SQL.

Comment: Thanks again for everything! Everything working now without error.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields = array( "RunnerID", "EventID", "Date", "FinishTime", "Position", "CategoryID" );

    $orderby = 0;
    $asc = 0;
    if( isset($_GET['orderby'])) $orderby = (int)$_GET['orderby'];
    if( isset($_GET['asc'])) $asc = (int)$_GET['asc'];

    $sql = "SELECT RunnerID, EventID, Date, FinishTime, Position, CategoryID, AgeGrade, PB FROM Results";

$sql .= " ORDER BY " . $fields[$orderby];
$sql .= " " . $asc ? "ASC" : "DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the *server* do the work, consider having the *browser* do it instead. Offloading work to the browser is an extremely useful skill, especially with very busy websites.

Put the data into a table without regard for sort order. Then use JavaScript to implement sorting. There are plenty of ways of doing this, for instance:

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('mytable'),
    trs = tbl.rows, l = trs.length, i, tmp = [];
for( i=0; i<l; i++) tmp.push(trs[i]);
tmp.sort(function(a,b) {
    // compare the rows how you want.
    // return -1 if a comes before b
    // return 1 if b comes before a
    // return 0 if they are equal
});
for( i=0; i<l; i++) tbl.appendChild(tmp[i]);
```

You can also look into one of the many plug-ins out there on the internet to do this, such as Footable.

Of course, you can always support non-JS users (how outdated are they?) with:

```
<noscript><a href="?sort=asc">Sort ascending</a></noscript>
```

When that parameter is present, do the sorting server-side for them, as per the other answers. The overwhelming majority of the time, though, it will be done with JavaScript.